# If $x\perp \mathrm{span}\{r_1,\dots,r_p\}$, can we prove $x\notin\mathrm{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_p\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Notations**: For a scalar $a\in\mathbb{R}$, denote 
$$\mathrm{sgn}(a)=\left\{
          \begin{array}{l l}
            1  & \mbox{if } a>0\\
            0  & \mbox{if } a=0\\
            -1 & \mbox{if } a<0
          \end{array}.\right.$$
For a vector $r\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathrm{sgn}(r)$ is element-wise.

Now we have a set of vectors $r_1, \dots, r_p\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $p<n$. The corresponding sign vectors are $v_1,\dots,v_p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$\mathrm{sgn}(r_i)=v_i$$
which implies that the elements of $v_i$ can only be $1$, $-1$ or $0$.

**Question**: Given a nonzero vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $x\perp \mathrm{span}\{r_1,\dots,r_p\}$, can we prove $x\notin\mathrm{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_p\}$? If not, can you given any counterexamples?

Comment: For a start, the zero vector is orthogonal to everyone and is also in every subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @mercio: do you mean the vector $x$ can be zero? I have revised the question and excluded that trivial case. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: we have $x=v_1+v_2+v_3$ when
$$
(r_1,r_2,r_3,x,v_1,v_2,v_3)=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&-3&1&1&1&-1\\
1&-2&2&1&1&-1&1\\
-2&1&1&1&-1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
**Edit.** Here is a better example:
$$
(r_1,r_2,r_3,x,v_1,v_2,v_3)=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&-5&1&1&1&-1\\
1&-5&1&1&1&-1&1\\
-5&1&1&1&-1&1&1\\
1&1&1&3&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The key is, each $v_i$ contains a negative entry, but the entries of $x=v_1+v_2+v_3$ are all positive. So we have a great liberty to pick some $r_1,r_2,r_3$ that are orthogonal to $x$.

Comment: So it is a valid counterexample with the extra zeros... nice "cheat". But still valid :)

Comment: @adamW No cheat now.

Comment: Nice counterexamples, though I was hoping that statement can be proved as correct:) Both examples are good. In the first one, $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are linearly dependent. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses $p=n$ thus strictly speaking is incorrect. It may serve as an example as to why that restriction is necessary for the question though.

Using row vectors, look at
$$\{r_1,\dots,r_p\} = \pmatrix{1 & 7 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ -2 & -6 & 0}$$
$$ x = \pmatrix{3 & -1 & 4 }$$

Then
$$\{v_1,\dots,v_p\} = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 & 0}$$

The $r$ do not have full span and $x$ is perpendicular to them. After applying the sgn(), the $v$ set has full span, as may be seen with the simple row operation to upper triangular from adding the first row to the other rows:
$$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\}$$
Thus a counterexample is given.

It may be more difficult to find a counterexample if given the additional restriction that each $r$ is independent, but I believe it could be given in that case as well.

Comment: How did you come up with that?

Comment: ok I did just notice that you have $p<n$. Let me know if you want me to erase this while I look at another possible counterexample.

Comment: @K.Stm. pretty much randomly. The sgn() function acts differently and non-linearly, so the key to this one is that I used $p=n$, which as my previous comment notes is not useable...

Comment: Thank you. Nice counterexample. Though $p=n$, it reveals a useful fact: even if $[v_1,\dots,v_p]$ is of full rank, $[r_1,\dots,r_p]$ may not.